# Input a JSONArray into swagger API for a springboot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger

I am new to using springboot and swagger, so not very familiar with this stuff. But what I want to do is to input a JSONArray into a swagger API and get the input into a controller. So, I have the following controller code:

```
@RestController
public class NameRegisterController{
  @Autowired
  private NameRegisterService service;
  
  @Postmapping(path="/control")
  public void NameRegisterAdd(@RequestParam JSONArray NameList)
  {
    service.addNames(NameList);
  }
}
```

Here, addNames is a function which takes JSONArray as input. When I go to the swagger API, I add the input as:

```
["name1","name2","name3"]
```

Unfortunately, when I execute, I get the error

```
"ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type[java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.RequestParam org.json.JSONArray] for value 'name1'; nested exception is org.json.JSONException: JSONArray test must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1"
```

I don't get it because the first character of my input is "[" as put in the swagger API. Would be very grateful if someone can provide some help.
My swagger is in my work environment, so am inserting similar pictures from the internet.

[image: This is what I get]
[image: This is what I want]

The first pic is what I get. The second pic is what I want

Comment: Spring has extensive auto-conversion capabilities for you. Don't manually handle `JSONArray`, use `List<String>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I want to get the kind of API in second picture to enter the array like ["a","b","c"]. But I get the one with the add button like in the first pic . Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

String Array

Frontend Pass with HTTP request

```
[“a”,”b”,”c”]
```

Backend receive in controller methods

```
@RequestParam String[] ids
@RequestParam List<String> ids
```

And I dont see you defining which request parameter name it should be looking at?

Example:

```
public String inputControllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam") List<String> myParam){

}
```

=== Edited ===

**You can't.**

Using the [Add String Item] button you must insert 1 String at a time.

However if they are not Strings, but rather an Array of Objects, then swagger allows you to write the array:

[image]

Use this https://editor.swagger.io/#/ to see an example.

Documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/

Your other option also if you really dont want the user to enter and you are limited by specific options is an enum:

```
parameters:
  - name: "status"
    in: "query"
    description: "Status values that need to be considered for filter"
    required: true
    type: "array"
    items:
      type: "string"
      enum:
        - "placed"
        - "approved"
```

Then the user simply selects multiple/all options:

[image]

Comment: The problem with changing the @RequestParam to List<String> is that when I got to the Swagger API, instead of entering something like ["name1","name2","name3"], I had to enter them one by one with the Add String button'. Actually, my requirement is that the person who would use the code wants to enter the input like ["name1","name2","name3"] on the swagger. Wondering if that is possible.

Comment: Please add pictures of your swagger and what you want

Comment: I added some similar pics as I cannot take screenshots in work environment. Basically, I get that add item button. But what I want is like the second pic, to type in as an array like ["name1","name2","name3"]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. My customer wants to insert in the API like ["name1","name2","name3"] . The options aren't limited, so I don't think an enum would work here.

Comment: I understand @ArnabGhosh Unfortunately you are limited here. Lets see if anyone else knows of a hack, but looking at the documentation, it does not appear possible for a String[] array